# C++ Performance of loops: Variable initialization

Tags: c++, performance, variables, initialization

A variable will be set to a value thousands of times. Would it be better performance-wise to check whether the variable has already been set to value like this:

```
    int a = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (a != 3) a = 3;
    }
```

or should I just leave it:

```
    int a = 0;
    while (true) {
        a = 3;
    }
```

P.S. I did some actual testing with 15000 iterations of each in Visual Studio 2010 (with `#include ctime` and `clock()` function) and they both gave the same 62ms in results. So does it mean that there is no actual difference?

Comment: Right, the compiler probably produces exactly the same assembly code (you can always check that to be sure).

Comment: You may want to define `int a` as `volatile int a` instead, so that its assignments do not get optimized away. Whatever the case, the solution is really to rewrite your code so that the constant variable doesn't need to change (you could use the `const` keyword to see where this is the case).

Comment: If the code is actually integer assignment, then test-and-load has to require more instructions than just load. If this is a sample for a more complex assignment (e.g. class or struct copying) then we'd need to see that code.

Comment: If optimizations are disabled, it's always faster to set an `int` than to test and either branch or set the variable.  But the same may not be true for Objects, and today's optimizing compilers are usually pretty good at branch prediction.

Comment: u must break the loop by putting else condition

Comment: gcc/g++ v4.7 optimizes the entire loop away at `-O3` optimization level. There is not even any loop code for *either* code blocks because the optimizer can see that the result is constant. Even with a non-infinite loop, the compiler just does a `load 3->a` once.

Comment: You must have an INCREDIBLY fast computer to finish an infinite loop 15000 times in 62ms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I'd say that with comparing it would be slower than simply assigning the value. But in practice this will hardly matter.

Do you have performance issues? Or think about optimizing? Keep in mind: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 3):

Setting a variable requires one memory access. Reading a variable and comparing it with a constant also requires one memory access.

If you do 15000 iterations, the first one will do 15,000 compares and 1 set, for a total of 15,001 memory accesses. The second one will do 15,000 sets, a total of 15,000 memory accesses. So the first one should be slightly slower, but you didn't do enough iterations to notice it.